# Getting an error with frame.add() not sure why

Tags: java, swing

so im making a simple box from java and this is the code so far:

import java.awt.Canvas;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

```
public class Display {

    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int LENGTH = 600;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display game = new Display();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, LENGTH);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

im getting an error here "frame.add(game);" its says "The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Display)"

How im not sure what im doing wrong, im using javaSE-1.6

Comment: I'm probably missing this, but what is "Display"?

Comment: ohh i didnt add all of it, its the class EDIT okay there fixed the code snippit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to add an instance of `Display`, which isn't a Swing component, to your `frame`, hence the error.  Looking at your imports, you probably meant to add a `JPanel` within your `Display` class (if there is one) to the `frame`.

Alternatively, your `Display` class needs to inherit from something like `JComponent`, if you want to add it directly. You shouldn't mix AWT and Swing components needlessly.

Comment: could you fix it for me? Im having trouble with it

Comment: @StanleyDharan Afraid it's impossible to fix without seeing the entirety of the Display class - and if that's it then your logic is wrong.

Comment: thats it excluding the package, im trying to just make a basic window with nothing on it atm

Comment: @StanleyDharan If that's the case then you don't need to add anything to it - just remove that line entirely.

Comment: Might be a nice idea to read through http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: I removed the line it seems to be fine now. @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is correct. I rewrote your first sentence to clarify the antecedent. Sorry for the heavy-handed editing; please refine as desired.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Correct, initially I assumed since he imported `Canvas` in the provided code, he had initialised a canvas he wanted to add somewhere else.

Comment: @berry120 Actually I discovered that after removing the code hadn't worked as it wouldn't let me debug it. But oddly enough I re added the function frame.add(game); and it didn't give me any errors not sure why but once again I am very happy of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your display needs to extend Component as that is what the `add` method expects as a parameter. It's probably a good idea to make it a JPanel.

You mention that you just want a basic window. This will do the trick:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Display extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Display();
    }

    public Display() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I just removed the line. But I really appreciate it :)